# How to declare getter in Typescript class

Tags: typescript

How do I *declare* (not *define*) a getter inside a Typescript class?

Something like:

```
class Foo {
   declare get bar();
   ...
}
```

The actual implementation is added dynamically via some nonsense Javascript annotation, but I want to make Typescript aware that it exists.

Comment: Hmm, how about creating an `interface` i.e. `interface DeclaredVars` with optional `readonly bar?: boolean;`? It will make TypeScript aware that it *may* exist in this class, right? At the same time the property will not be defined in the class so there's no risk of overriding the `bar` property after this *nonsense JS annotation* defines it. Does it make sense?

Comment: A little bit more writing but here's a demo how it could be achieved: https://repl.it/repls/HurtfulPrudentTelephones. So you don't define a property but you can try to access it and modify later. Type declarations are required.

Comment: @altocumulus I wasn't sure if that's what the OP was asking for. Ok, will post then ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an interface with the optional property? It will make TypeScript aware that it may exist in this class. At the same time, the property will not be *defined* in the class so there's no risk of overriding the bar property after *this nonsense JS annotation* defines it. A little bit more writing but here's a demo how it could be achieved:

```js
interface DeclaredVars {
  bar?: boolean;
}

class Some implements DeclaredVars {

  constructor() {
    console.log((this as DeclaredVars).bar);
  }
}

const s: DeclaredVars = new Some();
console.log(s.bar);
s.bar = true;
console.log(s.bar);
```

[Live demo](https://repl.it/repls/HurtfulPrudentTelephones)

So you don't define a property but you can try to access it and modify later. Type declarations are required.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as a property.

```
class Foo {
  bar: string; // or whatever type the getter returns
}
```

This is because when you consume the class, you will use `bar` as a property.

```
console.log(foo.bar);
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's safe in this case? From what I understand, the OP has also some JS annotation support (don't know from where, tho) which adds the property later. Is there a risk of overriding the property defined by the annotation with this approach?

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work - I'll update the question.

Comment: Actually it might work. Let me try. The reason I think it might not is because I'm using `vue-class-component` which processes properties and adds them to Vue's `data` object.

Comment: The TypeScript compiler will not create a property for bar.